# To get number of views of a SharePoint page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve the number of views of SharePoint page.
After searching on google I found a javascript that gets the number of views using JavaScript with the help of ViewLifeTime property.

Below is the JavaScript code for reference:-

```
var context;
    var web;
    var list;
    var currentItem;
function get_Views(){ 
  context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    currentItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId)
    context.load(currentItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText('PageGuid:"{' + currentItem.get_fieldValues("UniqueId").UniqueId.toString() + '}"');
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    context.executeQueryAsync(SearchDone, onQueryFailed)
}

function SearchDone() {
    var viewCount = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[0].ViewsLifeTime;
    alert(viewCount);
   //Use JQuery to show the viewCount on the page
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    //Error Logging
}
```

But it gives me an error on the following line:-

```
var viewCount = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[0].ViewsLifeTime;
```

Error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ViewsLifeTime' of undefined

After debugging I found out that there are no ResultRows in ResultTables.

What could be the reason for this error as I am able to see the number of views on SharePoint site?

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your script after sp.js loaded,

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(customfunction, "sp.js");
function customfunction(){
//your code logic
}
```

Update:

You may try below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(customfunction, "sp.js");
        function customfunction() {
            SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.search.js', "/_layouts/15/sp.search.js");
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.search.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery', function () {
                var context;
                var web;
                var list;
                var currentItem;
                function get_Views() {
                    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    web = context.get_web();
                    list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
                    currentItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId)
                    context.load(currentItem);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
                }

                function onQuerySucceeded() {
                    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
                    keywordQuery.set_queryText('PageGuid:"{' + currentItem.get_fieldValues("UniqueId").UniqueId.toString() + '}"');
                    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
                    results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(SearchDone, onQueryFailed)
                }

                function SearchDone() {
                    var viewCount = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[0].ViewsLifeTime;
                    alert(viewCount);
                    //Use JQuery to show the viewCount on the page
                }

                function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                    alert(args);
                }
                get_Views();
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it failed. It didn't give any result.

Comment: It gives me an error on the following the line
`!SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefined($v_0)`

Comment: It's hard to know the reason just with which statement caused error, you need use developer tool to debug the detailed error.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to debug the code and let you know.
Is there any other way you know, where can I use 'like' functionality for SharePoint page.

Comment: Hi @Lee_MSFT, I have tried the like functionality code from the following link:- [link](https://gist.github.com/sjkp/5563092#file-sp2013link-added-to-articleleft), but it still gives me following error:- **_spbodyonloadfunctionnames is not defined**. can you help me on this?

Comment: Hey, @Lee_MSFT can you help me on above question?

Comment: Do I need to create any Managed property in SharePoint site for this ?

Comment: Above code don't use Managed property, so I think you don't need create it.

Comment: because it is giving error on the same line as while debugging I found out that `ResultRows` is undefined.

Comment: You need create the search managed property https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27069.sharepoint-2013-showing-page-views-within-a-sharepoint-page.aspx, I misunderstanding as term managed property.

Comment: Well thanks @Lee_MSFT for help, that was the only remaining part I guess.